# Writing a Prometheus query that returns 1 only when gauge starts reporting data within the last 1 minute

Tags: prometheus

I would like to write a Prometheus query on a metrics that looks like below:

The metric is a gauge that looks like `task_info{namespace="my_namespace", phase="Running|Completed"}`. For the case of `phase="Completed"`, it will only ever report 1 once it is completed (and will keep reporting 1 forever afterwards), but not reporting anything before that (so no 0 reporting ever).

The goal of the query is to return 1 if at a given timestamp, only within the last 1 minute, the metric start reporting `phase="Completed"` under some namespace. The output set of vectors should contain the label `namespace`.

I have tried the following but neither works:

1. If I use `absent_over_time(task_info{namespace="my_namespace", phase="Completed"}[1m])` as an `and` condition to filter, it works if I specifically target a single namespace. However, it does not work since I want possibly one result per namespace.
2. I have also attempted `(sum_over_time(task_info[1m:]) == sum_over_time(task_info[3h:])` as a filtering `and` condition, which basically hopes that if the sum of the two equals, then the first report of the gauge = 1 must be within the last 1 minute or older than 3h, and I have ways to filter out the 3h case. However, when I plug this into my query, it does not yield the result I expected.

Is there a way to implement this in PromQL?

Comment: you can do something like the sum < 1 but > 0

Answer (score 0):

You could use `count_over_time()`. If the scrap interval of the `task_info` metrics is `15s`, then there should be 4 sample points in the last `1m`. In other words, `count_over_time(task_info[1m]) = 4`. If any metric is less than 4 but greater than 0, you can determine that it was reported in the last 1 minute.

`(count_over_time(task_info[1m]) < 4)*0+1`

[image]